# Is there a way way to add a "preprocess" to a UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, uiviewanimation

I want to add an animated effect when a UIButton is touched. Is there a way to run a function before the Button is sent off to its action?

Comment: You can add images for selection and normal state. This way button press can be indicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont see a reason for you to preprocess the touch event to button.
You can declare the animation in ViewDidLoad of your ViewController,

```
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
animation.duration = 2.0
animation.fromValue = self.testView.layer.position
animation.toValue = CGPoint(x: self.testView.layer.position.x + 100, y: self.testView.layer.position.y)
```

Here am animating the position property of button's layer, you can modify whichever property you feel like animating :)

Now in IBAction of button

```
self.yourButton.layer.add(animation, forKey: "position")
//this is necessary, you have to set the position again once the animation complete as core animation simply removes the animate object from layer once animation finishes 
self.testView.layer.position = CGPoint(x: self.testView.layer.position.x + 100, y: self.testView.layer.position.y)
//call your method do whatever you wanted to do once button tapped
//example : lemme print my name
print("sandeep")
```

Comment: These are great answers! Thanks. Sandeep, I'm doing some other processing as well.

Answer (score 1):

Following action is invoked when you start pressing button.

```
@IBAction internal func buttonTouchDown(_ sender: AnyObject)
```

And this one is invoked when you remove your finger (you tap button).

```
@IBAction internal func buttonTouchUpInside(_ sender: AnyObject)
```

So at first action you can start animation and at second you can end animation and do rest of your code. It should be enough unless you need other gestures.